# Save WinForm or Controls to File

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization

I have been working on an application which allows the user to make a label template for printing purposes by adding label controls to a panel(which I use as a container).  I have reached the point where I need to be able to save the template to a file which I can load into memory later for printing.  Since the form is not serializable does anyone have suggestions on how I can save the form or container(with added label controls) to a file that can be reused later?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a struct that contains enough information (and no more) about each `Label` that you can reconstitute the `Label` from it.
2. Write a method that takes a `List<MyStruct>` and populates a `Panel` from your structs.
3. Write methods to serialize and deserialize this list.
4. Encapsulate the whole thing in a class.

Comment: That is exactly what I thinking after reading OG's answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Got it all coded up and it is working perfectly now. Thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't directly serialize a form to a file. Sounds like you need to create a class that will hold the state of the user's work. You should then serialize that class to and from a file. There are built in methods for that using either Binary or XML Serialization.

Comment: @Nathan: Note that if you use this method, you must create your controls dynamically again based on the data present in the state class.

Comment: That probably wouldn't be a problem.  I would just have get the important property information from each control and then serialize it to file correct?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would serialize it as JSON.
When bringing it back you can use a generic method 
that loops through and sets the properties through reflection.
Also take notice that the library I've linked to will automatically serialize objects that you pass to it.

[JSON](http://json.org/)

[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

```
[{ "Label": [{"Top": 102}, {"Left": 105}, {"Text": "blah, blah"}] }]
```

**From JSON.NET**

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": new Date(1230422400000),
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It uses the [**`ISerializationSurrogate`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogate.aspx) interface to get around the problem of the form object not being serializable:

**How to serialize an object which is NOT marked as 'Serializable' using a surrogate.**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Surrogate_Serialization.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position, size and other properties about the form's controls at runtime and save that state in an XML or JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't trivial, but personally I would set up a function that can be called recursively that would add nodes to an XML file.

I don't have actual code, but pseudo-code looks like this: (you will need to do some clean-up, because I'm doing this off the top of my head without the aid of Intellisense.)

```
XmlDocument doc;

function SaveForm()
{
   doc = new XmlDocument("FormInfo");
   foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
   {
      AddControlToXml(ctrl, doc.Documentelement);
   }
}

function AddControlToXml(Control ctrl, XmlNode currentNode)
{
   XmlNode n = new XmlNode;
   Node.InnerText = ctrl.Name;
   foreach(Control ctrl2 in ctrl.Controls)
   {
      AddControlToXml(ctrl2);
   }

}
```

Comment: Looks like C# to me. (Except for the JavaScript function declaration.)

Comment: I don't see the recursion here... this is first level iteration

Comment: Um.. AddControlToXml calling AddControlToXml... A subroutine calling itself as needed based on child controls of the control passed to it...   What's the definition of recursion again?

Comment: @ChaosPandion - thanks for the edit.  I was on the way out the door for a meeting as I was finishing that up.  I didn't se that I forgot to format it as code.